# Draw Arc horizontally on a view layout

Tags: android, android-canvas

**Task** : To animate arc with alpha, scaling pulse

I have done almost everything using this Code : "https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid/blob/master/pulsator4droid/src/main/java/pl/bclogic/pulsator4droid/library/PulsatorLayout.java"

The only change I want to do instead of full circle I want half of it only arc would be great. But this drawn shape should be from **bottom to top** and placed **horizontally** on view.

I have searched half of the Internet for implementing this silly thing but 
my drawn arc or circle is either like : "(" or ")" I want this *curved* shape to be facing top like in Some **outgoing radiation type**.

Answer (score 0):

Have a refference from this link

https://github.com/DevLight-Mobile-Agency/PulseView

This will generate a wave from your icon's shape..
So i believe, for semi-circle wave, the requirement will be a semicircle icon .

Comment: No i can't use any drawable i have to draw since draw icon image have with issue like edges and corners are blunt even after anti aliasing set to true

Comment: And if placed on large screen the edges will look like ladder while in draw your pixel is perfect for every screen. See my link I just want an arc or semi circle. Instead of draw Circle i need draw Path or Draw oval whatever.